# I have many questions about a specific chapter in a book. Do I ask this as multiple questions or as one?

Tags: discussion

I'm currently reading through *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*. Chapter 9 has left me with such confusion that I have somewhere in the region of 7 questions worth of content to ask about. They span several topics, such as how certain events could have happened, why characters made certain decisions, and addressing apparent continuity errors, but they all fit neatly in to the topic of chapter 9.

How do I go about asking this? Do I make one big question to the effect of "What is causing these many strange events in chapter 9"? Or do I ask several smaller questions that may have related answers?

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to just have a discussion about everything in the chapter you can check out [the main site chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe) or even [create a specific room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new) for discussion of the chapter.

Comment: Is this your first  time reading through the book? If so, you may want to specify that in your questions so that people can answer without giving too much away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing the questions I can't tell for sure but this feels like it would certainly be in the realm of being closed as "Needs more focus". To have multiple questions in one post they generally need some bigger connection than that they all stem from the same question.

To me why a character made decision X and is Y a continuity error are almost certainly going to end up being two distinct questions and should likely be asked as such. That doesn't mean you can't group any of them together but you have to try and group them in a way that makes sense and so the questions are logically linked to each other in a way that would be sensible for one answer to answer.

I'd also like to put a note on the bottom here: if you're going to be asking several questions all on a similar topic please try not to spam them all at once. Space them out a bit. That will also give the questions the added benefit of having some time to breathe and get the attention they deserve rather than some getting lost in the mist.

Comment: As to the last point, if they are all *related*, it's likely that the answers to some of the earlier ones will also provide answers the later ones and obviate the need for them to be asked.